Issues with Access Token Retrieval and Validation in Nuxt 3 Application using Sidebase Nuxt-Auth with Keycloak
I'm currently developing a Nuxt 3 application and have integrated authentication using Sidebase's Nuxt-Auth module with Keycloak as the identity provider. The authentication flow works as expected, and users can log in/out without any issues. However, I've encountered a problem when attempting to use the issued access token to make authenticated requests to my Spring Boot backend.
Problem Description:
After a successful authentication, I try to retrieve the access token using the Nuxt-Auth getToken method with the intention of using this token for subsequent API requests. Unfortunately, the token I receive seems to be invalid or not the expected access token. Furthermore, I suspect the token retrieved is the Nuxt-Auth session token, not the Keycloak access token I require for my backend requests.
Here's the snippet where I attempt to retrieve the token:
// Token retrieval endpoint in Nuxt
import { getToken } from "#auth"

export default eventHandler(async (event) => {
    const token = await getToken({ event, raw: true, secret: process.env.NEXTAUTH_SECRET });
    console.log(token);
    return token || 'no token present';
});

And this is how I've configured the Nuxt-Auth handler:
// NuxtAuthHandler configuration
import KeycloakProvider from 'next-auth/providers/keycloak';
import { NuxtAuthHandler } from '#auth';

export default NuxtAuthHandler({
    secret: process.env.NEXTAUTH_SECRET,
    providers: [
        KeycloakProvider.default({
            clientId: process.env.KEYCLOAK_CLIENT_ID,
            clientSecret: process.env.KEYCLOAK_CLIENT_SECRET,
            issuer: process.env.KEYCLOAK_ISSUER_URL,
            idToken: true,
            wellKnown: process.env.KEYCLOAK_WELLKNOWN,
            authorization: {
                params: {
                    redirect_uri: `${process.env.NEXTAUTH_URL}/api/auth/callback/keycloak`,
                },
            }
        }),
    ],
    callbacks: {
        jwt({ token, account, user }) {
            console.log(token, account, user);
            return token;
        },
        session: (data) => {
            return data.session;
        }
    },
});

According to the official documentation, the jwt callback should be used to add the access token to the session. However, in my case, this callback does not contain an access token, and both account and user objects are always undefined.
Questions:

How can I ensure that the access token issued by Keycloak is correctly retrieved and valid for use with my Spring Boot backend?
Is there a step or configuration I might be missing to properly integrate the access token into the session object for subsequent use?
Is it possibly a misconfiguration in Keycloak that the access token is not included in the callbacks?

Any guidance or insights into resolving these issues would be greatly appreciated.
Edit:
Somehow I got it working, I can't really say how. I deeply debugged the lib and changed my configuration back and forth and now I got it running. Unfortunately my actual commit is way too big to reconstruct what the solution was. One keypoint was that the sessionStrategy needed to be jwt for the callback to be executed correctly.
Therefore this question can be closed.

use below config for adding access_token into session
callbacks: {

jwt: async ({ token, user, account }) => {
  if (account && account.access_token) {                
    token.accessToken = account.access_token; // <-- adding the access_token here
    token.refreshToken =account.refresh_token;
  }

  const userResponse = await $fetch("http://localhost:8000/api/v1/me/");

  token.data = userResponse;

  return token;
},
async redirect({ url, baseUrl }) {
  return baseUrl + "/dashboard";
},
async session({ session, user, token }) {
  session.token = token;
  
  return session;
},

}
and create a composable composables/useUserData.js
export const useUserData = async () => {
const { getSession} = useAuth();
const userData = await getSession();
return userData.token|| null
};

now you can access access_token and user data by calling composables in your components
const user = await useUserData();


Hey thanks, for your input but as I described in my question, the jwt callbacks token and account parameters are alway undefined. Also I linked the documentation that shows your approach, it's just not working for me

Also to mention that the token parameter from jwt callback does not contain the access_token. Only username, email and some openId related infos.

refer [https://sidebase.io/nuxt-auth/recipes/azure-ad-example]

Thanks for your effort, But as i edited in my original post, I already fixed the problem. Also your link is incorrect

I'm having the same problem with laravelpassport provider. Any way to get this access token?
